# Python: `Request exception` problem of google cloud storage using python code

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have a code for file download from a google cloud storage.

My code works perfectly, but sometimes there is a `request exception` problem.

This is my exception message:

```
requests.exceptions.readtimeout: httpconnectionpool
ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Until now, I solved the problem by rebooting my computer or killing the 443 port process through the `pkill` command.

But this is not a perfect solution. I need your help if there is a problem with my code.

This is my code:

```
class GCP_Storage_Resource:
    def __init__(self):
        BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket name'
        storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('Resources/Token/storage_private_key.json')
        self.bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    def get_resource_file(self, source: str, location: str) -> None:
        blob = self.bucket.blob(source)
        blob.download_to_filename(location)


gcp_storage_resource = GCP_Storage_Resource()
gcp_storage_resource.get_resource_file(source='...', location='..')
```

I referred to stack overflow and GitHub, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Please review my code and give me some advice.

Comment: Show more of your code. Where in your code is the exception occurring (the actual line of code)? From your question, I do not know where you are running this code and under what structure (python directly, proxy web server, etc). Your problem could be a poor Internet connection, running out of memory, etc.

Comment: The code is almost the majority of the code, where the problem occurs is 'blob = self'.Occurs in bucket.blob(source)'.

Comment: This problem occurred after restarting the program hundreds of times, and when port 443 in the tcp connection pool was full.

Comment: Even if you download the file successfully, 443 ports are in the "Settings" state. In my opinion, some connection was not closed after downloading.

Comment: I ran python code directly on PC.